# Charles map remote stuck

Tags: charles-proxy

I used "map remote" in Charles 4.2.1 using a proxy to an iPhone SE iOS9.3.2. After doing what I had to do, I removed the "map remote" with not success.

The URL is still mapped to a remote URL and it is frustrating as I can't any longer go to the actual URL.

So far, I tried:

1. removing the map through `tools > map remote`.
2. removing ALL maps through `tools > map remote`.
3. uncheck the "enable map remote" in `tools > map remote`.
4. remove the proxy + quit Charles + restart the device.

Nothing seems to help, it is like the URL is forever bound to the new URL.

So, is there a way to fully reset/restore/clear/clean any remote mappings created with Charles, other than the obvious `tools > map remote`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CharlesProxy acts as a proxy when performing remote maps (instead of sending 301 to your browser that would be cached), so I guess the only reasonable explanation to your issue is that your browser has cached the URL's content. 
Have you tried clearing your phone's browser cache?

Comment: Marked as the answer as is the only thing that worked.